# TFS Automatically promote new and renamed files

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Any time a new file is created, or an existing one is renamed, that file is automatically excluded in the pending changes. We have to promote all of those files in order for them to actually be checked in with the changeset. How can I change this so that all new/renamed files are always INCLUDED automatically?

Why is excluding them the default behavior? I can't imagine any scenario where you could or would desire to exclude them. If the new files are referenced elsewhere in the solution, it would obviously break and not compile for anyone who pulled the changeset with the missing files.

Comment: Hi. You are using TFVC source control, right? Could you share the TFS version and reproduce steps here? In addition, we could try to [unbind and rebind the problem project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/0eh3790h(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and try again.

Comment: Yes, thanks for checking back. This is still an issue, but I can't figure out how to find which version of TFS I'm using.

To reproduce the steps, I just add, delete, or rename any file (class or module). Any time I do that, the added/deleted/renamed file is automatically excluded, and I have to manually promote it for inclusion.